# MySQL : Find duplicate records but EXCLUDE the first one from the list

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a table below:

```
MariaDB [groupdb]> select * from album;    
+----+---------+---------+
| id | artist  | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | ArtistX |   45677 |
|  2 | ArtistY |  378798 |
|  3 | ArtistX |   45677 |
|  4 | ArtistZ |  123456 |
|  5 | ArtistY |  888888 |
|  6 | ArtistX |    2312 |
|  7 | ArtistY |  378798 |
|  8 | ArtistY |  888888 |
|  9 | ArtistY |  888888 |
+----+---------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

I attempted to find duplicate records with the query below:

```
MariaDB [groupdb]> select * from album where artist IN (select artist from album group by artist having count(artist)>1) and user_id IN (select user_id from album group by user_id having count(user_id)>1);
+----+---------+---------+
| id | artist  | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | ArtistX |   45677 |
|  2 | ArtistY |  378798 |
|  3 | ArtistX |   45677 |
|  5 | ArtistY |  888888 |
|  7 | ArtistY |  378798 |
|  8 | ArtistY |  888888 |
|  9 | ArtistY |  888888 |
+----+---------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

This is all good and fine. Though I want my resultset to have a list of duplicates excluding the first one. i.e similar to the one below.
**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | artist  | user_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  3 | ArtistX |   45677 |
|  7 | ArtistY |  378798 |
|  8 | ArtistY |  888888 |
|  9 | ArtistY |  888888 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

As you can see above, It's a list of duplicates excluding the first one.

**NOTE:** For a record to be a duplicate, both the *artist* and *user_id* must be the same.
My challenge is coming up with a query leading to that resultset above.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use HAVING, and MAX().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to handle in recent versions of MariaDB which support `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY artist, user_id ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM album
)

SELECT id, artist, user_id
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Here is what the intermediate CTE used in the above query would look like:

```
+----+---------+---------+----+
| id | artist  | user_id | rn |
+----+---------+---------+----+
|  1 | ArtistX |   45677 | 1  |
|  2 | ArtistY |  378798 | 1  |
|  3 | ArtistX |   45677 | 2  |
|  4 | ArtistZ |  123456 | 1  |
|  5 | ArtistY |  888888 | 1  |
|  6 | ArtistX |    2312 | 1  |
|  7 | ArtistY |  378798 | 2  |
|  8 | ArtistY |  888888 | 2  |
|  9 | ArtistY |  888888 | 3  |
+----+---------+---------+----+
```

Note that artist/user_id pairs which have no duplicates would only ever be assigned a row number of 1, and so would never be retained in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works fine. Is it possible to achieve the same without depending on the id in your query?. I tried changing the `ORDER BY` to something else like `ORDER BY artist` but now the id's are off.

Comment: Well going by your sample data, the `id` column is what determines which of the duplicates are first or last.  In place of `id`, you may use any column which can also represent this order.

Answer (score 3):

You want to select all rows for which exists a sibling with a smaller ID. The simplest way to express this is in my opinion:

```
select * 
from album a
where exists
(
  select * 
  from album a2
  where a2.artist = a.artist
  and a2.user_id = a.user_id
  and a2.id < a.id
)
order by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to get one row per artist/user_id:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by artist, user_id order by id) as seqnum
      from album a
     ) a
where seqnum > 1;
```

In older versions, you can use:

```
select a.*
from album a
where a.id > (select min(a2.id)
              from album a2
              where a2.artist = a.artist and a2.user_id = a.user_id
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB 10.3 and above support `except` function so you could simply do

```
select id, artist, user_id
from t
except 
select min(id), artist, user_id
from t
group by artist, user_id;
```

If that's not an option, you could use `not in`

```
select id, artist, user_id
from t
where (id, artist, user_id) not in (select min(id), artist, user_id
                                    from t
                                    group by artist, user_id);
```