# Is it possible to remove duplicates based on multiple columns in Laravel's ORM?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-8

Users can re-submit results for the competition and it updates the results on the scoreboard, however, it also creates a save of the result for the "Way back when" feature of being able to view results previously to see improvements of scores.

The issue I have is that duplicate entries exist for certain months, the only thing that changes in the database is the primary key `id`, the `created_at` and `updated_at`. If the column values: `discipline_n` where`n` is `one` through `six` are all the same as any others  should not be queried, ie:

```
id 1                                     id 2
username foo                             username foo
discipline_one 4                         discipline_one 4
discipline_two 5                         discipline_two 5
discipline_three 8                       discipline_three 8
discipline_four 9                        discipline_four 9
discipline_five 4                        discipline_five 4
discipline_six 6                         discipline_six 6
created_at yesterday for example         created_at today for example
updated_at yesterday for example         updated_at today for example
```

Should be considered a duplicate and thus be removed from the result. I've tried to use the `distinct()` function built into Laravel's ORM but I'm still getting duplicates. Can this be done with just SQL? My expected output here would be:

```
id 2
username foo
discipline_one 4
...
```

Where `id 1` is ignored as a duplicate. I've tried:

```
$waybackWhen = \App\Models\ResultSave::where('username', $result->username)
    ->distinct([
        'discipline_one',
        'discipline_two',
        'discipline_three',
        'discipline_four',
        'discipline_five',
        'discipline_six',
    ])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played around with it a little bit from a question I asked some time back.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (PARTITION BY username, discipline_one, discipline_two, discipline_three,
     discipline_four, discipline_five, discipline_six ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM results
)

SELECT id, username, discipline_one, discipline_two, discipline_three,
     discipline_four, discipline_five, discipline_six, created_at, updated_at
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Credits: @tim-biegeleisen [MySQL : Find duplicate records but EXCLUDE the first one from the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60852907/7376590)

##### Before

| id | username | discipline_one | discipline_two | discipline_three | discipline_four | discipline_five | discipline_six | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | qivr | 489 | 23 | 1 | 2 | 89 | 34 | 2021-11-21 17:49:28 | 2021-11-25 18:40:26 |
| 7 | foo | 4 | 5 | 8 | 9 | 4 | 6 | 2021-11-01 19:45:01 | 2021-11-01 19:45:42 |
| 8 | foo | 4 | 5 | 8 | 9 | 4 | 6 | 2021-11-02 19:45:15 | 2021-11-02 19:45:46 |
| 9 | foo | 4 | 5 | 8 | 9 | 4 | 6 | 2021-11-03 19:45:20 | 2021-11-03 19:45:50 |

##### After

| id | username | discipline_one | discipline_two | discipline_three | discipline_four | discipline_five | discipline_six | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | qivr | 489 | 23 | 1 | 2 | 89 | 34 | 2021-11-21 17:49:28 | 2021-11-25 18:40:26 |
| 9 | foo | 4 | 5 | 8 | 9 | 4 | 6 | 2021-11-03 19:45:20 | 2021-11-03 19:45:50 |

##### Laravel

```php
    public static function waybackWhen($result)
    {
        $username = $result->username;

        config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', false);
        DB::reconnect(); // Important as the existing connection if any would be in strict mode.

        $resultSet = DB::select("
            WITH cte AS (
                SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                (PARTITION BY username, discipline_one, discipline_two, discipline_three,
                 discipline_four, discipline_five, discipline_six ORDER BY id DESC) rn
                FROM results
            )
            
            SELECT id, username, discipline_one, discipline_two, discipline_three,
                 discipline_four, discipline_five, discipline_six, created_at, updated_at
            FROM cte
            WHERE rn = 1 AND username = ? 
       ", [ $username ]);

        // Now changing back the strict ON.
        config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', true);
        DB::reconnect();

        return $resultSet;

    }
```

##### Output

```sh
=> [
     {#3409
       +"id": 9,
       +"username": "foo",
       +"discipline_one": "4",
       +"discipline_two": "5",
       +"discipline_three": "8",
       +"discipline_four": "9",
       +"discipline_five": "4",
       +"discipline_six": "6",
       +"created_at": "2021-11-03 19:45:20",
       +"updated_at": "2021-11-03 19:45:50",
     },
   ]
```

Comment: Thank-you so much, I really appreciate you linking your question also. This is a great way to approach it! Although, I suspect there is an SQLi without escaping the contents of `$username` here so I'll research now how to use RAW SQL queries in Laravel whilst using prepared statements.

Comment: For future viewers, this can be done [by binding the parameters](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.2/Connection.php#L323) like normal in PDO

Comment: @Jaquarh , Thank you as well for the parameter binding suggestion. I've refactored my answer accordingly.